# PNG file is NOT keeping transparency?

Tags: php, php-gd

I'll be using these variables throughout:

```
$ROOTDIR = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$ROOTFILE = "http://www.scottandjessiecooper.com/webtutorials/images/smiley.png";
$NEWFILE = "$ROOTDIR/images/tmp/new_smiley.png";
```

When I use this function, I have NO problems with transparency

```
function save_image($root, $saveto){
    copy($root, $saveto);
}
save_image( $ROOTFILE, $NEWFILE ); // root can be file or url
```

However I **NEED** to use an **IMAGE_RESOURCE** so i cam manipulate the **ROOTFILE** if needed

So i treid this:

```
if ( file_exists( $NEWFILE ) ) unlink ($NEWFILE);
$image = imagecreatefrompng( $ROOTFILE );
imagepng( $image, $NEWFILE );
imagedestroy( $image );
```

Now when I use this:

```
<img src="<?=$NEWFILE?>" />
```

I lose the transparency. The background goes BLACK!

So I tried outputting the image to make sure it wasn't the **saving** that caused the problem:

```
if ( file_exists( $NEWFILE ) ) unlink ($NEWFILE);
$image = imagecreatefrompng( $ROOTFILE );
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng( $image );
imagedestroy( $image );
```

Still to no avail...

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enabled alpha blending and save alpha. I found this after a 10 sec google search:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php#43024

Comment: I just searched "imagecreatefrompng transparency".

Comment: I read the function documentation for `imagecreatefrompng` and found nothing useful, my bad

Comment: i also find difficulties in saving 8/16/24 png images with transparency and used many times some scripts, producing some big php chunks trying to cover every case (true color or 256 etc.). Not so easy stuff.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and found prehfeldt's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10718745/1852838) has the right idea but didn't actually help me solve this. The practical way to enable saving alpha channel information is by calling [imagesavealpha](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php) on your image resource before you output it to file:

```
imagesavealpha($image, true);
imagepng( $image, $NEWFILE );
```

When you don't do this, by default GD will discard the transparency information when you save or output the image. The reason `copy` didn't cause this problem for you is that its a simple byte by byte copy at the file level without going through any image processing at all.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not in the `GD` or the `PHP`.

The problem is in the Photoshop.

If you save `PNG` file while you are on `RGB mode` and not on `Indexed mode`.

Comment: this actually fixed it for me in gimp too, while no code could

Answer (score 1):

this helps?

```
$info = getimagesize("smiley.png");
$image = imagecreatefrompng("smiley.png");
$image_new = imagecreatetruecolor($info[0],$info[1]);       
if ( ($info[2] == IMAGETYPE_GIF) || ($info[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG) ) {
  $trnprt_indx = imagecolortransparent($image);   
  if ($trnprt_indx >= 0 ) {   
     $trnprt_color    = imagecolorsforindex($image, $trnprt_indx);   
     $trnprt_indx    = imagecolorallocate($image_new, $trnprt_color['red'], $trnprt_color['green'], $trnprt_color['blue']);   
     imagefill($image_new, 0, 0, $trnprt_indx);   
     imagecolortransparent($image_new, $trnprt_indx);
  }
  elseif ($info[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
     imagealphablending($image_new, false);   
     $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image_new, 0, 0, 0, 127);   
     imagefill($image_new, 0, 0, $color);   
     imagesavealpha($image_new, true);
   }
}
imagecopy($image_new,$image,0,0,0,0,$info[0],$info[1]);
imagepng($image_new,"smiley2.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the background is black, try the following:

```
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); 
// Make the background transparent 
imagecolortransparent($im, $black);
```

(Transparency in PNGs is never perfect thorugh PHP)

Comment: you say transparency in png's aren't good in php, is there another way?

Comment: The problem with this is, it takes ALL the black, and turns it transparent. I just want to keep the ORIGINAL transparancy. Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you checked out imagemagick functions? But if prehfeldt's answer's got you sorted, use that (and give him a tick!)